# Relation between diagonalizibilty of linear operator and its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Hoffman-Kunze (Linear Algebra) there is this theorem :
[image]

The first two statements are equivalent, does this means if characteristic polynomial can be factored in the above way then **T** is diagonalizable?

But consider :

[image]

Characteristic Polynomial of **A** satisfies statement 2 but matrix **A** is not diagonalizable, So statement 1 and statement 2 are not equivalent. Am I missing something, Please Help.

Comment: The second statement has **two** clauses: one is the factorizability of the characteristic polynomial, and the second clause is the connection between the exponents of the linear factors and the corresponding eigenspaces. Your matrix may satisfy the factorization clause, but not the dimensionality clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: The second statement has two clauses. It asserts that **two** things happen:

1. The characteristic polynomial splits; **and**
2. The dimension of the eigenspace of $\lambda$ equals the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a root of the characteristic polynomial for every eigenvalue $\lambda$.

So the second statement is not just about being able to factor the characteristic polynomial.

Second: by my calculations, your matrix has characteristic polynomial (expanding along the second row)
$$\begin{align*}
\det(A-tI) &= \det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
6-t & 3 & -8\\
0 & -2-t & 0\\
1 & 0 & -3-t
\end{array}\right)\\
&= (-2-t)\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
6-t & -8\\
1 & -3-t
\end{array}\right)\\
&= (-2-t)\Bigl( (6-t)(-3-t) + 8\Bigr)\\
&= (-2-t)(t^2 -3t - 10) = -(t+2)^2(t-5).
\end{align*}$$

Let us write then $c_1=-2$, $d_1=2$, $c_2=5$, $d_2=1$, using the notation of the theorem.

It is true that it is not diagonalizable, because $W_1$, the nullspace of $A+2I$, has dimension $1$. But this means that it does **not** satisfy the second statement, because $\dim(W_1) = 1 \lt 2=d_1$. That is, $A$ does **not** satisfy the second statement in the theorem, because it has two satisfy two clauses and it only satisfies one of them.

Answer (score -1):

$(\textrm{ii})$ In other words what it says is that $\textsf T$ is diagonalizable if and only if the dimension of each eigenspace associated with $c_i$ is equal to the multiplicity of the same eigenvalue $c_i$.

In your case, you forgot to check the dimension.

Comment: Well, it says more than that; it also requires that the characteristic polynomial split. The standard matrix of the map $T(x,y) = (-y,x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfy your “In other words” by vacuity (since it has no eigenvalues), but is not diagonalizable.

Comment: You're right, but I think what I said anyway is another way of interpreting the same thing as the statement says. Thanks!

Comment: Well, no, because what you said is *wrong*: it’s missing the first clause of what the statement says. You have certainly zeroed in on what the OP missed, but when you also assert that this thing is the whole of the statement, then you are straying into false territory.